# Using C# to recursively get a collection of controls from a controlcollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, controlcollection

Currently I am trying to extract a collection of dynamically created controls (checkboxes and dropdownlists) from a recursive control collection (repeater).  This is the code I am using.

```
private void GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection, ref List<T> resultCollection)
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(T))
            resultCollection.Add((T)control);

        if (control.HasControls())
            GetControlList(controlCollection, ref resultCollection);
    }
}
```

I am having problems with the following line:

```
resultCollection.Add((T)control);
```

I get the error ...

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'T'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need generics here ? All controls derive from System.Web.UI.Control

Comment: The `ref` is not needed on the list parameter btw.

Comment: I wanted to be a be able to specify what web control I wanted to extract.

Comment: @MadHur, he wants to do stuff like `GetControlList<TextBox>(...)` I am assuming.

Comment: You also need to use controlCollection.Controls in the last line of code.  Otherwise, you will be in an endless loop of recursing through the original control collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem:

Since `T` can be a `reference type` or a `value type`, compiler needs more information.

You can not convert and `Integer` to `Control`.

### Solution:

To fix this, add **`where T : Control`** or **`where T : class`** (a more general) constraint to state that `T` will always be a reference type.

### Example:

```
private void GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection, ref List<T> resultCollection)
where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        //if (control.GetType() == typeof(T))
        if (control is T) // This is cleaner
            resultCollection.Add((T)control);

        if (control.HasControls())
            GetControlList(control.Controls, ref resultCollection);
    }
}
```

- You also don't need `ref` keyword. Since, List is a reference type, it's reference will be passed.

Comment: As @codethis mentioned in another comment, the last line should be GetControlList(control.Controls, ref resultCollection);

Answer (score 3):

Change it to

```
var c = control as T;
if (c != null)
    resultCollection.Add(c);
```

This will be faster than your cod, since it doesn't call `GetType()`.
Note that it will also add controls that inherit `T`.

You'll also need to constrain the type parameter by adding `where T : Control`.