# Recursively extract dynamically created controls in a repeater, Part II

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

To be fair, this is a part two follow up to [Using C# to recursively get a collection of controls from a controlcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463319/using-c-to-recursively-get-a-collection-of-controls-from-a-controlcollection) - and rather than heap another question onto the old one, I created a new one.  Here is the code that I'm using:

```
private void GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection, ref List<T> resultCollection) where T : Control 
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        if (control.HasControls())
            GetControlList(control.Controls, ref resultCollection);
        else if (control is T)
            resultCollection.Add((T)control);
    }
}
```

and is involked like this when the form is submitted

```
List<CheckBox> checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>();
GetControlList(RepeaterCapability.Controls, ref checkboxes);
```

The problem is that I don't get any results when I clearly added several during the repeater OnItemDataBound event.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

REsolved ... PEBKAC

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Repeater.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.items.aspx) property?