# Iterate though all controls on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, css, iteration

I'm using ascx and I need to iterate through all of the controls and selects each that have cssClass attribute set to 'required'.

I have the following code:

```
foreach (Control masterControl in Page.Controls)
        {
            if (masterControl is MasterPage)
            {
                foreach (Control formControl in masterControl.Controls)
                {
                    if (formControl is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm)
                    {
                        foreach (Control contentControl in formControl.Controls)
                        {
                            if (contentControl is ContentPlaceHolder)
                            {
                                foreach (Control childControl in contentControl.Controls)
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

however.. i cannot access childControl.CssClass. How do I access it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

[`CssClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property is a member of the [WebControl class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx).

You have to check if the control is a webcontrol, or, if it's only a control, you can get the attribute "class" in the attributes collection.

for example, you can do :

```
List<WebControl> wcs = new List<WebControl>();
GetControlList<WebControl>(Page.Controls, wcs)
foreach (WebControl childControl in wcs)
{
     if(childControl.CssClass == "required") {
          // process the control
     }
}
```

You also have to iterate recursively. Code found here : [Using C# to recursively get a collection of controls from a controlcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463319/using-c-to-recursively-get-a-collection-of-controls-from-a-controlcollection) :

```
private void GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection, List<T> resultCollection)
where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        //if (control.GetType() == typeof(T))
        if (control is T) // This is cleaner
            resultCollection.Add((T)control);

        if (control.HasControls())
            GetControlList(control.Controls, resultCollection);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the following but it still would not work..                   if(childControl is WebControl)
                                        {
                                            childControl.CssClass
                                        }

Comment: do not forget that ChildControls is not recursive

Comment: Thanks heaps Steve. One thing arises now. I cannot access the Value property of the web controls? Why is that?

Comment: Value is not a member of webcontrol. What are you tryning to do exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx) class doesn't have that CssClass property, the [WebControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx) does. So try to cast your `childControl` to WebControl. If that worked, then you can access the CssClass property.

```
WebControl webCtrl = childControl as WebControl;
if (webCtrl != null)
{
   webCtrl.CssClass = "test";
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Hans. One thing arises now. I cannot access the Value property of the web controls? Why is that?

Comment: @Johan: same problem. "WebControl" doesn't have a Value property so you need to cast it further to the "real" type - which will only work if it really is that type.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment on the answer above, you need to first check that it is a `WebControl` and then cast it to a `WebControl`

```
var webControl = childControl as WebControl;

if(webControl != null)
{
   if(webControl.CssClass == 'required')
   // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: CodeAnalysis would complain that you are casting twice ("is" and "as"). Better (as in faster) would be to use just "as" and then check for null.

Comment: Did not know that! Thanks for the tip. Not sure it deserved a -1 though as we are talking nanoseconds, if that. And my code would work.